# How to set auto recovery for all instances in autoscaling group via AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I am working on building a AWS quick start and trying an optimized solution for - setting auto recovery for all instances in autoscaling group in cloudformation template.

Today, I am setting auto recovery per instance via launchconfig (i.e. script to query instance-id and put-metric-alarm for instance-id), but these alarms does not get deleted via "delete-stack" operation.

Can someone help share thoughts/examples for better handling this?

Comment: Are you talking about [Instance Recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)?  I don't think that's meant to be used with auto-scaling groups.

Comment: Are you using the CLI "put-metric-alarm" to create the metrics? then try to delete the stack via cloud formation? If yes, Cloudformation can only manage the resources create from the stack. it works as expected.